# simple addition within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When the user clicks the button to show all values in the array, how can I get it to add up the total of all 'amounts due'? For example, if one user enters $5, another enters $10 and another enters $25, the total would be displayed as $40.

```js
// Code goes here

var customerarray = [];

function displaydata() {
  var innerTemphtml = ' ';
  for (var i = 0; i < customerarray.length; i++) {

    innerTemphtml += customerarray[i].customerName + " " + customerarray[i].customerID + " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue;
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = innerTemphtml;
}

function addtoarray() {
  customerarray.push({
    customerName: document.getElementById('custName').value,
    customerID: document.getElementById('CustID').value,
    AmountDue: document.getElementById('Amount').value
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <span>Customer Name: </span>
<input type="text" id='custName'/><br><br>
<span>Customer ID: </span>
<input type="text" id='CustID'/><br><br>
<span>Amount: </span>
<input type="text" id='Amount'/> <br><br>
<button onClick="addtoarray();" class="button" type = "button">add to array</button>
<button onClick="displaydata()" class="button" type = "button"> Display data</button>
<p id="output"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code as per your requirement as shown below.Hopefully it will solve your problem

```js
// Code goes here

var customerarray = [];

function displaydata() {
var total=0;
  var innerTemphtml = ' ';
  for (var i = 0; i < customerarray.length; i++) {

    innerTemphtml += customerarray[i].customerName + " " + customerarray[i].customerID + " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue+"<br/>";
    total+=parseInt(customerarray[i].AmountDue);
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML ="User Input Data <br/>" +innerTemphtml;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Grand Total = "+total;

}

function addtoarray() {
  customerarray.push({
    customerName: document.getElementById('custName').value,
    customerID: document.getElementById('CustID').value,
    AmountDue: document.getElementById('Amount').value
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <span>Customer Name: </span>
<input type="text" id='custName'/><br><br>
<span>Customer ID: </span>
<input type="text" id='CustID'/><br><br>
<span>Amount: </span>
<input type="text" id='Amount'/> <br><br>
<button onClick="addtoarray();" class="button" type = "button">add to array</button>
<button onClick="displaydata()" class="button" type = "button"> Display data</button>
<p id="output"></p>
<p id="total"></p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `"AmountDue"` property of object to number instead of string at `.push()` call

```
Number(document.getElementById('Amount').value)
```

use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to add two elements of array at a time, return sum

```
let dues = customerarray.reduce((a, {AmountDue:b}) => a + b, 0);
```

Comment: `.value` should be stored as number to avoid casting string to number which can lead to `NaN`. `customerarray.push({
    customerName: document.getElementById('custName').value,
    customerID: document.getElementById('CustID').value,
    AmountDue: Number(document.getElementById('Amount').value)
  });`, `let dues = customerarray.reduce(({AmountDue:a}, {AmountDue:b}) => a + b);`

Comment: That reduce function is going to behave very, very poorly if there are 0 or 1 entries. You'd be better served putting a map in front, and adding an initial value to the reduce.

Answer (score 0):

There are mutliple things you have to look. I have added a display due() for you.
And here is my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jinspeter/1qxo50uz/
You have to user a number field for Amount. And also addding the amount has to parsed to Int to reject string.

```
  <body>
       <span>Customer Name: </span>
    <input type="text" id='custName'/><br><br>
    <span>Customer ID: </span>
    <input type="text" id='CustID'/><br><br>
    <span>Amount: </span>
    <input type="number" id='Amount'/> <br><br>
    <button onClick="addtoarray();" class="button" type = "button">add to array</button>
    <button onClick="displaydata()" class="button" type = "button"> Display data</button>
    <button onClick="displayTotalDue()" class="button" type = "button"> Display Due</button>
    <p id="output"></p>

      </body>

var customerarray = [];

function displaydata() {
  var innerTemphtml = ' ';
  for (var i = 0; i < customerarray.length; i++) {

    innerTemphtml += customerarray[i].customerName + " " + customerarray[i].customerID + " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue;
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = innerTemphtml;
}
function displayTotalDue(){
 var total =0;
    customerarray.forEach(function(item){
   total = total + item.AmountDue
  });
  var innerTemphtml = 'totalDue=' + total;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = innerTemphtml;
}
function addtoarray() {
  customerarray.push({
    customerName: document.getElementById('custName').value,
    customerID: document.getElementById('CustID').value,
    AmountDue: parseInt(document.getElementById('Amount').value)
  });
  console.log(customerarray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to fix your code. To make it more easy to read. I put the `displaydata()` method inside of the `addtoarray()` method, so you can see the results after adding an element in the `customers` array. Also,  I replaced the `for` with a `forEach` and added a new div for the total.

I create a node that is a `p` tag, which will contain the name, id and amount. This tag then will be added to the `outputLabel` for each element in the array. You can optimize this by just adding the additional `node` and not running the entire array to print the output.

```js
// Code goes here

var customers = [];
var outputLabel = document.getElementById('output');
var totalLabel = document.getElementById('total');
var total = 0;

outputLabel.innerHTML = '<p>Customers</p>';
totalLabel.innerHTML = 'Total:  0';
function displaydata() {
  outputLabel.innerHTML = '<p>Customers</p>';;
  total = 0;
  customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    var node = document.createElement('p');
    node.innerHTML = customer.customerName + ', ' +
      customer.customerID + ', ' +
      customer.AmountDue;
    total += parseInt(customer.AmountDue);
    outputLabel.appendChild(node);
  });
  totalLabel.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + total;
}

function addtoarray() {
  customers.push({
    customerName: document.getElementById('custName').value,
    customerID: document.getElementById('CustID').value,
    AmountDue: document.getElementById('Amount').value
  });
  displaydata();
}
```

```html
<span>Customer Name: </span>
<input type="text" id='custName' /><br><br>
<span>Customer ID: </span>
<input type="text" id='CustID' /><br><br>
<span>Amount: </span>
<input type="text" id='Amount' /> <br><br>
<button onClick="addtoarray();" class="button" type="button">Add to array</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

**Optimized version**: for this version I moved the `node` (`p` tag) to the `addtoarray()` method and I capture the data from the `inputs`. Then I calculate the total. With this two values a call the `displaydata()`. This method save time running the array each time you want to print the added element.

```js
// Code goes here

var customers = [];
var outputLabel = document.getElementById('output');
var totalLabel = document.getElementById('total');
var total = 0;

outputLabel.innerHTML = '<p>Customers</p>';
totalLabel.innerHTML = 'Total:  0';

function displaydata(node, total) {
  outputLabel.appendChild(node);
  totalLabel.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + total;
}

function addtoarray() {
  var customerName = document.getElementById('custName').value;
  var customerID = document.getElementById('CustID').value;
  var amountDue = document.getElementById('Amount').value;
  customers.push({
    customerName: customerName,
    customerID: customerID,
    amountDue: amountDue
  });
  var node = document.createElement('p');
  node.innerHTML = customerName + ', ' + customerID + ', ' + amountDue;
  total += parseInt(amountDue);
  displaydata(node, total);
}
```

```html
<span>Customer Name: </span>
<input type="text" id='custName' /><br><br>
<span>Customer ID: </span>
<input type="text" id='CustID' /><br><br>
<span>Amount: </span>
<input type="text" id='Amount' /> <br><br>
<button onClick="addtoarray();" class="button" type="button">Add to array</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```